# Convert LINQ with multiple columns to Array (to be used by the 2nd LINQ)

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, linq

`USR_MSTR` - List of users who can use the application

`PERSONNEL_MSTR` - Repository for all users and their details (first name, last name, etc.).

My goal is to show the list of users who can use the application along with its details. So I made a LINQ to get the `USR_MSTR` and compare it with the 2nd LINQ that gets the `PERSONNEL_MSTR`. My problem is I'm not sure yet how to pass the other details aside from `EMP_ID` using array and use it for the 2nd LINQ.

Note: I can't use anonymous type as I'm having errors with that.

```
//Get list of login users
var users = from u in _odb.USR_MSTR
            select new UserInformationModel
            {
                empid = u.EMP_ID,
                startdate = u.BGN_DT,
                enddate = u.END_DT,
                usegroupid = u.USR_GRP_ID
            };

string[] userList = users.Select(u => u.empid).ToArray();

//Get user information of login users
var userPersonnel = from p in _odb.PERSONNEL_MSTR
                    where userList.Contains(p.EMP_ID)
                    select new UserInformationModel
                    {
                        empid = p.EMP_ID,
                        firstname = p.FNAME,
                        middlename = p.LNAME,
                        lastname = p.LNAME,
                        emailadd = p.EMAIL,
                        //Need to get the startdate, enddate and usergroupid from var users.
                        //How do I pass that to string[] userList and use it here?
                    };
```

Comment: Just use a `join` to link the tables on `EMP_ID` (only one query required)

Comment: But i need to use SQL's `IN` to get the personnels existing in the user table. As far as I know, LINQ don't have a direct equivalent to that. That's why I use 2 LINQs

Comment: Oh, I can see now your point. So aside from comparing it to the array of `userList` I can use `JOIN` to get the other details :) I feel stupid haha

Comment: `from p in _odb.PERSONNEL_MSTR join u in _odb.USR_MSTR on p.EMP_ID equals u.EMP_ID select new UserInformationModel { empid = p.EMP_ID, firstname = p.FNAME, ....., startdate = u.BGN_DT, ....};`

Comment: I'll let you know if it works, then you can add it as an answer so I can tag it as solved. Thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a simple left join.  One of the simplest ways to achieve this is by creating a view in your database.  That is a good direction if you will access the joined data often and from multiple (application) views.  However, overusing that approach can lead to your database having a glut of views which can become hard to maintain.  "Let the database do what it's good at"

The Linq statement is something like...

```
IEnumerable<UserInformationModel> collection = from u in in _odb.USR_MSTR
    join p in _odb.PERSONNEL_MSTR on u.EMP_ID equals p.EMP_ID
    select new UserInformationModel()
    {
        empid = u.EMP_ID,
        startdate = u.BGN_DT,
        ...
        firstname = p.FNAME,
        ...
    };
```

It's worth looking at [101 Linq samples](https://weblogs.asp.net/sbehera/101-linq-samples) for more info.  There are versions of this for lambdas as well, if you prefer.

Comment: @Stephen-Muecke Thanks, I didn't notice OP used the same model for both queries.  Also you snipped the answer in the comment while I was writing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use let right before the select.

```
let systemUser = users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.empid = p.EMP_ID)
```

This will set a variable called systemUser and you can get the info from systemUser.startdate, for example. Of course, you must check if it is not null before.